# Radio group string data saving in the SQLite database

Tags: android, string, android-sqlite

I have an list view with some set of questions and I have an radio group for each question. By the selection of radio buttons for the questions it wants to move to certain Activities and finally saves in database.

**For example:**

1. If I select the options for the questions like `yes,no,no,yes` it will go to one Activtiy
2. If the user selects the options for questions like `no,yes,yes,no` it will go to another Activity.

Finally it has to save the details in db, but it was entering not properly showing constants.

Comment: In what kind of environment are you working (programming language, web/desktop app/mobile app/...)?

Comment: This sounds like Java for Android.

Comment: i am working in android